# ng-pattern for angularjs wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

i am trying to work with ng-pattern but it throw an error. i want to validate a duration of time with the follwing pattern :

```
((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)
```

but i have this error :

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 76-76 [] in expression [((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?].

it seems that i have problem with back slash but what i know that if i want escaping back slash i have to make two back slash "\". the version of angularjs is 1.2.rc2

Answer (score 1):

You are actually escaping a white space character.
`\s` is a white space character in a regular expression so by doing `\\s` you are escaping the white space expression and because of this you are searching for a slash followed by an s: `\s`

What you might need is an extra closing bracket somewhere there...

Comment: the problem that i have generate the expression from a generator online and i have test it on this site : [link](http://regex101.com/r/aD6lY3) and it works fine.

Comment: It says in the explanation: 
"\\ matches the character \ literally
s? matches the character s literally (case sensitive)"
Because it matches zero or one times you get a match. But you don't want to search at all for a slash and a s